# Data encoding in Machine Learning experiments

Tags: encoding

Do we always need to encode data, both input and output or the ML algorithm take care of it?

like if for a classification problem, class label is 'Y' or 'N', is it necessary to convert it to 0/1 or ML algorithm will take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

The dependent variable "Y" is catagorical, so you're using classification algorithms instead of regression. These algorithms handle categorical data like yes/no. However, to build regression algorithms, you need to convert the catagorical data into numeric, which can be done using various encoding methods.